# C++ How to access elements in a vector of queues of an object

Tags: c++, class, vector, queue

So I have a class called PCB:

```
class PCB
{
    private:

        int PID;
        string filename;
        int memStart;
        string cdrw;
        int filelength;

    public:

        PCB();
        PCB(int, string, int, string, int);
        virtual ~PCB();
        void getParam();
};
```

And I have a vector of queues: `vector<queue<PCB>> printer;`

How would I access the first element of the first queue in the vector? How would I use my class functions? Would it look like `printer[0].getParam`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printer[0]` gives you access to the first `queue<PCB>`.

`printer[0].front()` gives you access to the `PCB` at the front of the queue of the first `queue<PCB>`.

`printer[0].front().getParam()` allows you to call the `getParam()` function on the the `PCB` at the front of the queue of the first `queue<PCB>`.

Comment: Thanks man, I was thinking of that, but I wasn't super sure about how to write the syntax for that.

Comment: @TheCoxer, no problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

A [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) only provides facilities to access the first and last items directly using `front()` or `back()`.  So if you want to call a function on one of those items from the vector then you would use

```
std::vector<std::queue<PCB>> printer;
// fill printer
printer[0].front().getParam();
// or
printer[0].back().getParam();
```

In short

```
printer[some_index].front()
// or
printer[some_index].back()
```

Returns a reference to the `PCB` in the container at that index.

Comment: What if I wanted to call two methods on the same object?

Comment: @bdbasinger then you would use `printer[some_index].front().func1;` and then `printer[some_index].front().func2;`.

Comment: Using .front() again wouldn’t cause it to move to the next item in the que after using it the first time?

Comment: @bdbasinger front only gives you a reference to the first element.  It does not remove anything.  To remove you need to use pop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using your code;

```
int main()
{
    vector<queue<PCB>> printer;

    // Create object your PCB class.
    PCB pcbObject;

    // Declare a queue
    queue<PCB> que;

    // Add the PCB class object to queue
    que.push(pcbObject);

    // Push the queue to vector.
    printer.push_back(que);

    //Get the first value
    printer[0].front().getParam();

    // Remove the element PCB
    printer[0].pop();

    return 0;
}
```